# Rename a published Artifact wthout the build pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, artifact

If I want to archive an artifact, I would like to rename the artifact without using the build pipeline.
Is there a possibility to rename the artifact

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a possibility to rename the artifact?

Currently, **changing the name of an existing artifact is not supported.**

You can use pipelines to regenerate and rename artifacts, but the names of already generated artifacts cannot be changed.